# Mount share folder on windows

Tags: linux, mount, cifs

I am trying to mount to a Windows share folder from RedHat Linux, I have below code in **/etc/fstab**

```
//TheWindowsIP/ShareFolder /LinuxPath/LinuxFolder cifs username=username,password=password,domain=windowsDomain,dir_mode=0777,file_mode=0777 0 0
```

When I run "**mount -a**" I got a "**Resource temporarily unavailable**" error, can someone tell me how can I solve this issue? Or maybe advise another way to access the window folder from RedHat Linux(cifs is driving me crazy)

Answer (score 0):

OK, after the tremendous effort of searching and trying in different ways, turns out the only action I need to solve this problem is **reboot**. I guess, somehow, the content in /etc/fstab will be mount correctly when the Linux start, but cannot be mount properly when I run **mount -a**. Ahhh what can I say...